# Verifying CRC using airpcap and pcap

Tags: c, pcap, wifi

I'm writing an application in C using `airpcap` and `pcap` libraries. I want to ask if there is a ready function to check the `CRC` (`FCS`) of received packets or whether it must be calculated manually. In airpcap's Control Panel you can setup the `FCS` filter.

One of the functions of the application will be something similar to site survey. I want to ask how to list discovered networks in order not to duplicate them. Compare the `ssid` or maybe there is a simpler way; is there some parameter which is unique to a network?

Comment: I guess the most unique value of a given network is its BSSID.

Answer (score 2):

First I would check whether the driver is providing the `OS` with the invalid frames. If your driver is capable of providing these invalid frames - then the rest is up to you. Checking the code of `aircrack-ng` (or a different tool) should give you an idea.

*Side note for site survey*: I would focus on identifying different `BSSIDs` which should give you idea about the radios in the neighbourhood. Same `SSID` can be used for many overlapping `BSSes` (of course at some point you'd be needing it as well). Have a look at the different 802.11 frames (start with something easy - like `Beacon Frame`).

Comment: @Szymon: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30185/you-versus-you-as-polite-form-of-writing

Comment: Thanks for your advises. I already riped 802.11 frame by type and subtype. In aircrack-ng they using build in function to accept only valid frames and I don't want to drop the invalid frames but recognize them, I will try to look for other open source projects

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark has a CRC-32 function that it uses to check Ethernet and 802.11 FCSes when available; check out its Ethernet and 802.11 dissectors.  It's licensed under the [GNU Public License, Version 2](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html).

Comment: Yes I know I'm already studing wireshark's code but it's a huge project and its hard for me to find useable things but I keep on trying.